# Jmeter-simulate 150 logged in users on the website and make request to other page with logged in status

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, stress-testing

I have a scenario where I have to simulate 150 logged in users on the system and they will be making request to a different page at the rate of 8 requests per second with login status.

How do I do this
Assumption 1: Thinking of having two http samplers one for login functionality and other one for requesting the page I wanted (Select product page). But my doubt is, is this the right way to simulate the logged in user on the other page(select product page)? as login and select-product page requests are in different HTTP samplers, their access rights will be treated differently I guess and I will be ending up as an anonymous user on the 
select-product page instead of logged in user. Please suggest a solution.

I don't want to login each time I make a request to select-product page as the login is big bottle neck which takes lot of time, rather I would like to log all users at first than use the logged in users to ping select-product page with logged in status.

If I have multiple HTTP samplers (for login, select-product), number of request to server are increasing, but at all times I want to limit number of requests to 8 only.

Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check links and tips below for solutions:

1. If you put your Login and Select Product samplers under the same [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - login and select product actions will be executed by the same thread.
2. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan. It'll keep session information so the same (and unique for each thread) session will be used per thread.
3. To perform login only 1 time place the relevant sampler under [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
4. To limit load to 8 requests/sec only use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer).

Hope this helps.